# Restore Truncated Data In Mysql

Tags: mysql

Unfortunately i have truncated a table data in `MySql` is there any chance to get the data back??? in `MySql` workbench? if there is any chance please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Certainly. Restore it from your backup. You *do* have a backup, right? If not, you're out of luck (and hopefully will learn a valuable lesson for the future).

Comment: you can't get your data back, if you don't have backup